# Print shell environment functions on a single line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

In bash, running `set` will display all environment settings. I want to display my functions as a single line for each function. So instead of running `set` and getting this (for example):

```
gcm ()
{
    git commit -m "$@";
    git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit
}
gcma ()
{
    git commit -a -m "$@";
    git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit
}
```

I want to see this:

```
gcm () { git commit -m "$@"; git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit }
gcma () { git commit -a -m "$@"; git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit }
```

So I think I want a sed/awk command that will look for regex `' ()$'` and concatenate every line following (with a space separation char) until the regex `'^}$'` is matched, and anything else should just print as is.

UPDATE: All of the examples submitted so far take all the input and render it on a single line, and that's not exactly right. I want each function (the set of `' ()$'` to `'^}$'`, inclusive) as a single line.

Comment: Just a detail : a semi-colon `;` may be missing just before the `}`, in your single line version.

Comment: @yolenoyer The last line in a function does not interpret a colon, so it is not displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Small [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) script

Try this:

```
declare -f gcm gcma dequote quote |
    sed '1h;1!H;/^}$/!d;s/.//;x;s/\n[ \o11]*//g;s/}$/;}/'
```

may render:

```
gcm () { git commit -m "$@";git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit;}
gcma () { git commit -a -m "$@";git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit;}
quote () { local quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'};printf "'%s'" "$quoted";}
dequote () { eval printf %s "$1" 2> /dev/null;}
```

I've added semi-column in order to be able to source the output.

### Stronger

This version will parse output of `set` command without argument and take **all, but only** functions:

```
set | sed '/^[a-z0-9A-Z_.-]\+ () *$/,/^}$/{ //{ /()/{h;d;}};H ;/^}$/!d;g;s/\n[ \o11]*//g;s/}$/;}/;p;};d'
```

This could by written:

```
set | sed '
    /^[a-z0-9A-Z_.-]\+ () *$/,/^}$/{
      //{
        /()/ {
            h;
            d;
          };
      };
      H;
      /^}$/!d;
      g;
      s/\n[ \o11]*//g;
      s/}$/;}/;
      p;
    };
    d;
'
```

Note: `[a-z0-9A-Z_.-]\+` is not well validated: I'm not completely sure about what a function name could contain.

### Detailled explanation

There is a runnable [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) script with line by line explanation

```
#!/bin/sed -nf
# -n modifier won't output anything without explicit 'p' command

/^[a-z0-9A-Z_.-]\+ () *$/ , /^}$/ { # from lines beginning by funcname, to ^}$
    //{                # At first or last line of block...
        /()/{          # If containing '()', 
            h;         # place this line in hold space,
            d;         # then delete (go to next line)
        };
    };
    H;                 # Append to hold space
    /^}$/!d;           # If not '^}$', delete this line (go to next line)
    g;                 # replace current line by hold space
    s/\n[ \o11]*//g;   # Suppress each new line and following spaces or tabs
    s/}$/;}/;          # Add semi-colon before last '}' in order to source
    p;                 # print
}
```

Copy this to a file you could call `bashFuncToOneLine.sed` then `chmod +x spacebashFuncToOneLine.sed`

```
declare -f gcm{,a}  | ./bashFuncToOneLine.sed 
gcm () { git commit -m "$@";git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit;}
gcma () { git commit -a -m "$@";git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit;}

set | ./bashFuncToOneLine.sed | less -S
```

Comment: This is almost correct. The 'add semi-colon' part isn't quite right. The `^commit};}` part should end up `^commit;}`. As is, the syntax of the resulting output is invalid.

Comment: This works: `sed -n '/^[a-z0-9A-Z_.-]\+ () *$/ , /^}$/ {//{ /()/h; /()/!H; }; //!H; /^}$/!d; g; s/\n[ \o11]*/ /g; s/}$//; p; }'` or minimized: `sed -n '/^[a-z0-9A-Z_.-]\+ () *$/ , /^}$/{ //{/()/h;/()/!H;};//!H;/^}$/!d;g;s/\n[ \o11]*/ /g;s/}$//;p; }'`

Comment: @DrStrangepork I was a little wrong (The last line was appended two times). This is correct now (and a little simplier). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'sub(/}/,"}\n")||$1=$1' ORS='' file
```

or remove `file` and pipe to it (in which case you need to `awk -v ORS=''...`). Result:

```
gcm (){git commit -m "$@";git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit}
gcma (){git commit -a -m "$@";git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit}
```

- replace `}` with `}\n`
- and use `ORS=''` to remove the (other than above) newlines
- and `$1=$1` to rebuild the records to trim space

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
awk  '{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ") ;ORS=(/}/?RS:FS)}1' f
gcm () {  git commit -m "$@";  git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit }
gcma () {  git commit -a -m "$@";  git --no-pager log -1 | grep --color ^commit }
```

Comment: This works until the very last function's `'^}$'` which always up on its own and not appended to its own function

Comment: @DrStrangepork - Can you please be more specific when you say - This works until the very last function's `'^}$'`

Comment: I used exactly what you typed, and `gcm` was exactly the above, but `gcma` had a linefeed after "commit" and then a '}' on a line all alone. And I replicated that pattern with any number of functions: everything up to the last one was correct, but the last one had the final '}' after a linefeed.